# Validation against Linq Entity properties

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, linq-to-sql, mvvm

I have a linq entity wrapped in a property that I have in my ViewModel:

```
public NA_Header Na_Header
{
    get
    {
        _na_header=Job.NA_Headers.FirstOrDefault();
        return _na_header;
    }
    set { _na_header = value; }
}
```

I use this Na_Header property in my view to update fields in my GUI (xaml):

```
<Toolkit:DateTimePicker BorderBrush="Gray"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding Path=Na_Header.JobStart, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource thisNullDateConverter}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Format="Custom" FormatString="MMM dd yyyy"/>
<Toolkit:DateTimePicker BorderBrush="Gray"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding Path=Na_Header.JobEnd, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource thisNullDateConverter},ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Format="Custom" FormatString="MMM dd yyyy"/>
```

Notice, I have 2 properties in this object that I want to validate against Na_Header.JobStart and Na_Header.JobEnd  (these are dates).  I have the ValidatesOnDataErrors set to true on each property.

Also in the ViewModel I have IDataError implemented:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "Na_Header")
        {
            if (Na_Header.JobStart > Na_Header.JobEnd)
                return "Job Stat Date must be an earlier date than Job End Date";
        }
        return "";
    }
}

public string Error
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Unfortunately, the DataError does not fire when changes are made to the JobStart or JobEnd properties.  I don't think I need NotifyPropertyChanged because it is a linq entity (which the PropertyChanged stuff is done automatically)

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you don't have a Linq entity as you put it.

IEnumerable First() is actually returning an object of type T, although you don't show your definition for field _na_header. I'd guess at that being a Job/Na_Job.

I would recommend that you have a couple of choices.

1. If your Job class is part of your ViewModel namespace (or you just want to get updates when it changes even in your Model layer), then implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This way the JobStart and JobEnd will update the Binding.
2. Instead of exposing the NA_Header property, why not expose JobStart and JobEnd instead (and then implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel, but I think you have already). This may simplify your ViewModel by hiding some of the classes in the Model tier, or it may make it more complicated, but at the benefit of simplified XAML.

Comment: I don't need INotifyPropertyChanged because it is part of the Linq system which automatically does this.  The property is saving fine, it was just not firing the DateError stuff.  I ended up doing the same thing you did in #2, which was just creating properties for JobStart and JobEnd and calling "return Na_Header.JobStart" (or Na_Header.JobEnd) within those properties.  I was trying to avoid doing it that way because I will need to validate other things this way as well, which means more code added, but maybe that's the only way. *shrug*